# Download large files from server via FrontEnd (Angular)

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, download, zip

I am facing issues in my application where I need to download zip files (packages) created by the backend services (on EC2 AWS).

We are using HTTP services in Angular to download the zip files. The issue is mainly when the zip file is more than 1.5 GB. The frontend fails to download large files and throws up 502/503 error.

Is there a solution where I can download large files via the frontend (Angular)?

Any help will be appreciated.